# Spring 4 Hibernate 4 integration - DispatcherServlet and different maven dependencies cause error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, integration, classnotfoundexception

I am doing my first web-app that integrates Spring REST with hibernate. I have separate html+css+jquery website, which handles my RESTful WebService. And my problem is this:

I did everything step by step to build the result I have now. And finally, when I run Tomcat, it runs ok. Then I am using IntelliJ IDEA builded REST client and check the most simple and the only one url: localhost:8080/room and recieve 404. 
I have found some advice on google to remove  from web.xml - and I did it. And now when I just run my Tomcat and test the url above for the first time, it serves an stacktrace:  http://pastebin.com/EMPDVCBy and then for every next time 404: Servlet dispatcherServlet is not available

Earlier I have received an: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

But I dont even know how, It has changed for some reason. 
I try to solve this problem for about 2 days and dont know whats the problem. I have entered every possible google's link that it has given me. Nothing helped.

Earlier, when there was only Spring project - it has worked normally. After adding entities, dependencies to hibernate, different side-libraries(dependencies to them) that are required, DAO's etc - it started causing a problem.

I also noticed, that after starting to integrate hibernate and spring I often receive stacktrace that was often telling me some ClassNotFoundException. From different places, even if I have aproperly dependencies added.

Have no idea what could I did wrong. It is really important for me to solve this. 
Appreciate if you help me.

I understand, that you will need my code, but it is so much of it, that It would be to long post :) tell me what you need I will post it here

edit
maybe the most important file, I think: web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     metadata-complete="true">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>responseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.maciej.filters.ResponseOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>responseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Filter is my own filter that adds headers to every response. Nothing big and important for this I think. When i delete those lines, It doesn't help.

Moment ago I removed my tomcat from intellij, removed my artifact and created everything from scratch. Now on localhost:8080/room I recieve HUGE stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/aMHqz40R

Comment: Are you sure spring web is in your pom.xml?

Comment: yes I do, 100% sure, I even tried to replace different versions: 4.0.0, 4.0.3, 4.0.4 etc

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, finally solved it.

Hibernate 4 can work without two dependencies of annotation and common-annotation. So if you have any dependency of annotation in your pom then remove it and make sure they are not part of it. My work pom is as

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- If using JPA (2), add: -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```